# Storage Space running out - can't access phone at all

Tags: insufficient-memory, file-management

I have an LG Volt (LS740).  Woke up this morning and couldn't get into the phone at all.  When swipe, I just get black screen. Notification indicates "**Storage space running out: Some system functions may not work**" but clicking on notification just gives me black screen.  Rebooting the phone doesn't seem to help.

I've gone thru similar questions posted but they all seem to have access to either Settings or a file manager.  I can't access any functions on the phone.  Occasionally I can get the icon desktop, but the system won't respond to taps.

Do I need a reset of the phone or is there some magic incantation I can perform to get some control back?

Answer (score 0):

My wife's been getting this on her Ls740 lately. A temporary fix is to go into settings / apps and sort by size. The app using the most space will show up at the top. In her case it's the "google play services" thats going crazy and using up all available memory (currently at 2.4 gb). Click on it and select "clear all data". That fixes it for about 24 hours but then it happens again. I still have not figured out whats causing it. I have the identical phone and do not have the problem.

I did try a factory reset too but it didn't solve the problem.